# Failed to run example Activiti Cloud application

Tags: docker, keycloak, spring-cloud, activiti

I am trying to run Activiti Cloud example in docker.
I am using this official tutorial:
https://activiti.gitbook.io/activiti-7-developers-guide/getting-started/getting-started-activiti-cloud/getting-started-docker-compose

All the prior steps succeeded till I try
"To start work, execute getKeycloakToken hruser in Postman Keycloak collection. Then run startProcess in rb-my-app Postman collection."

I succeeded to execute getKeycloakToken hruser in Postman Keycloak collection.
I failed to run startProcess in rb-my-app Postman collection.

I got 404 when I execute getModels in Postman modeling collection.
I got 500 when I execute startProcess in Postman rb collection.

The major error message in logs:

```
example-runtime-bundle             | 2022-03-08 19:08:30.970  WARN [rb,,] 7 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment   : Failed to load URLs from http://127.0.0.1.nip.io/auth/realms/activiti/.well-known/openid-configuration
example-runtime-bundle             | 
example-runtime-bundle             | java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

The related configurations:
in docker-compose.yml:

```
  keycloak:
    container_name: keycloak
    image: activiti/activiti-keycloak
    volumes:
      - ./activiti-realm.json:/opt/jboss/keycloak/activiti-realm.json
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - nginx

  example-runtime-bundle:
    container_name: example-runtime-bundle
    image: activiti/example-runtime-bundle:${VERSION}
    environment:
      # JAVA_OPTS: "-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=8000,suspend=n -noverify"
      SPRING_JMX_ENABLED: "false"
      ACT_KEYCLOAK_URL: "http://${DOCKER_IP}/auth"
      SPRING_RABBITMQ_HOST: "rabbitmq"
      SERVER_SERVLET_CONTEXT_PATH: /rb
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://activiti-postgres:5432/activitidb
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: activiti
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: mypassword
      SPRING_JPA_DATABASE_PLATFORM: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
      SPRING_JPA_GENERATE_DDL: "true"
      SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO: update
      # ACTIVITI_SECURITY_POLICIES_0_NAME: "HR Group restricted to SimpleProcess and ConnectorProcess"
      # ACTIVITI_SECURITY_POLICIES_0_GROUPS: "hr"
      # ACTIVITI_SECURITY_POLICIES_0_ACCESS: "WRITE"
      # ACTIVITI_SECURITY_POLICIES_0_SERVICENAME: "rb-my-app"
      # ACTIVITI_SECURITY_POLICIES_0_KEYS: "SimpleProcess,ConnectorProcess,fixSystemFailure,twoTaskProcess"
      # ACTIVITI_SECURITY_POLICIES_1_NAME: "testgroup not restricted at all"
      # ACTIVITI_SECURITY_POLICIES_1_GROUPS: "testgroup"
      # ACTIVITI_SECURITY_POLICIES_1_ACCESS: "WRITE"
      # ACTIVITI_SECURITY_POLICIES_1_SERVICENAME: "rb-my-app"
      # ACTIVITI_SECURITY_POLICIES_1_KEYS: "*"
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - nginx
      - keycloak
      - rabbitmq
      - activiti-postgres
```

in `.env`:

```
DOCKER_IP=127.0.0.1.nip.io
VERSION=7.1.0-M13
KEYCLOAK_REALM=activiti
KEYCLOAK_RESOURCE=activiti
```

Full logs output is here:
https://gist.github.com/chang4tech/affd504809249733ee1f553da1d03763

What am I supposed to do to debug/detect the problem and eliminate the errors?
Thanks.